# Doctrine: ManyToMany with ExtraFields, cant´t Access associations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following Entities:

The Sound Entity:

```
/**
  * Sound
  * @ORM\Table()
  * @ORM\Entity()
*/
class Sound {
   /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   protected $id;

   // ....

   /**
    *     @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SoundMember", mappe   dBy="sound")
    */
   protected $soundMembers;
}
```

The User Entity:

```
/**
 * User
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */

class User extends BaseUser{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SoundMember", mappedBy="user")
    */
    protected $soundMembers;

    // ...
}
```

And the "Join-Entity" with some extra Fields:

```
/**
 * SoundMember
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class SoundMember {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="soundMembers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sound", inversedBy="soundMembers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sound_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $sound;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="aExtraField", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $aExtraField;
}
```

From the Setup it seems okay - the symfony2 Toolbar shows no errors. 
If i access the the member in e.g. twig via soundMember.sound, it just says:

```
Key "sound" for array with keys "id, aExtraField" does not exist in ...
```

If i do a var_dump() on each member, it shows me the correct id, and the aExtraField value. But i can´t access the getSound or getUser on the SoundMember.

Whats my mistake? 
FYI: I removed the getter and setter for better readable. If they should be important, i will edit this Post.

Comment: Try accessing soundMember.sound.id in twig, by accessing soundMember.sound you're accessing the object directly. But yes please do post your setters/getters.

Comment: I faced the Problem - i made in the Repository a "getArrayResult". With "getResult" everything works fine. But why i can´t access it via the ArrayResult like other relations?